# Typescript convert array to associative array

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array that I want to turn into an associative array and need some help on the syntax.  I'd like to make the associative array read only.

I'm a typescript noob and apologize if this is a really basic question.

Given an array of associative arrays:

```
interface Greeting {
    name: String,
    punctuation?: String,
}

const GreetingArray: ReadonlyArray<Greeting> = [
    {name: "noob", punctuation: "!"},
    {name: "sam", punctuation: "."}
]
```

I fumbled my way into using `new Map<>` and `forEach`ing over elements, but I'm not sure how to make this compatible with ReadOnly map or general read only associative array.

What I'd like is to be able to convert my array of associative arrays into an object that supports dict/hashmap-like behavior for lookups, using the `.name` as the key and full associative array as an object (`{"noob": {name: "noob", punctuation: "!"}, "sam": {name: "sam", punctuation: "."}}`).

edit: removed distracting failed attempt per suggestion :)

edit2: removing even more unhelpful text from my question

Comment: Are you just looking for an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) instead of an object literal?  That is, change your `{`...`}` to `[`...`]` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w25LYW)?  If so I could write up an answer but this seems very close to "caused by a typo".  How should we proceed?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the help.  I think maybe it looks like a typo issue, but it's more my ignorance in the language.  I see that going to an array literal will give me an array of `name: element`, but I was hoping for an associative array of `{element.name: element}`.  I feel like I'm just fuzzing the interpreter trying to get the result I want.

Comment: Oh, so maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpjVaw) is what you want?  I'd advise you to remove the failed attempts from the question because they are only distracting; additionally, you should change `String` to `string` (the types are not the same and you almost never want `String` in TypeScript), as well as `GreetingArray` to `greetingArray`  and `MyReadOnly` to `myReadOnly` (this one is just naming convention; variables are almost always in lowerCamelCase)... and then I'll write up an answer explaining.  If it's not what you're looking for, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That's exactly what I want, thank you!  And agreed the failed attempt was distracting, but stackoverflow has a prompt box asking for "what you've tried" -- I didn't want to be rude and ignore it, even though I had a suspicion it was making my question worse.

Comment: Even the `let Assoc = new Map<String, Greeting>` part isn't really helping, since you're looking for a plain object, not a `Map`.  Instead you should probably put what you want the output value to look like (say by writing it out explicitly; "I want it to be an object equivalent to `{ noob: {name: "noob", punctuation: "!"}, sam: {name: "sam", punctuation: "."}}` and additionally it should be a readonly dictionary-like object").

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I think this is my lack of javascript/typescript experience bleeding through.

Comment: Side note: I would advise against using `reduce` and object concatenation here since the keys of the object are dynamic and potentially numerous. It is a better practice to construct an entries array and then create an object out of it, like so `Object.fromEntries(greetingArray.map(g => [g.name, g]))` or simply to manually set values as in the original post and then cast the `Map` as a `ReadonlyMap<string, Greeting>`

Comment: ^@geoffrey this is a good point

Comment: To elaborate a little: when you create an object in one go, the JIT creates a hidden class which enables fast property access (at least it's the case in V8). I'm not sure of what is going to happen if you repeatedly concat an object: usually the JIT creates transitions between hidden classes when you add props dynamically, which is expensive, but it may give up and use a hash map instead, so you loose read speed and/or write speed by doing this. Maps have better write speeds so setting values repeatedly is not bad, but the read speed is not as good as objects with fast property access

Comment: @geoffrey thank you as well.  for my knowledge, how do I cast a Map as a ReadonlyMap? Is it as simple as `const myMapRO: ReadonlyMap<T> = myMap;`?  I don't mean to lazy, but I think I'm still at the point of learning how to ask that are phrased properly for TypeScript experts to answer

Comment: You could do `const readonlyAssoc: ReadonlyMap<String, Greeting> = Assoc` or `const readonlyAssoc = Assoc as ReadonlyMap<String, Greeting>`

Comment: Actually I should not have said "cast". In TS you would say "assert the type of... to be..."

Comment: Thank you @geoffrey!  I really appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help me learn.  edit: I see your edit and thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you're looking for is something like

```
interface GreetingDict {
    readonly [k: string]: Greeting
}
```

which has a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) meaning that it could have any number of `string`-valued keys, each of which should have a `Greeting`-valued property associated with it.  And it's a [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) index signature meaning that the compiler will discourage people from doing any writes into it.  (Note that it just *discourages* such writes and does not *guarantee* that the writes cannot happen; it's a compile-time only construct, and TypeScript considers `readonly` properties to be mutually assignable to non-`readonly` properties, so it's easy enough to circumvent this by writing to the same object using a reference whose type isn't `readonly`.)

---

Given an array of `Greeting`s like

```
const greetingArray: ReadonlyArray<Greeting> = [
    { name: "noob", punctuation: "!" },
    { name: "sam", punctuation: "." }
]
```

you can convert it into a `GreetingDict` by [`map`ping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to an array of key-value pairs, and then using [the `Object.fromEntries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to
transform it to a single object.

```
const myReadOnly: GreetingDict =
  Object.fromEntries(greetingArray.map(g => [g.name, g]));
```

You can verify that this works as expected:

```
console.log(myReadOnly)
/* {
  "noob": {
    "name": "noob",
    "punctuation": "!"
  },
  "sam": {
    "name": "sam",
    "punctuation": "."
  }
}  */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/PTAEFcGcFNUgXATgSwHYHNQENUBNSoD28oAykmugDRzSwAW88ADpAFwgDu3AdPAJ7NokAMYpm8ADY50PQonTBchEZGD0cuAEaFCAayXQR0xFnjJCqALQAzZJOFLCVyFc1Xl1+JB6MAtpIAxKjgflrQiC4UGFY6hA44Lvxh8W54VoRaAFZG8ABQeWjwETZYIrAA4oh05higAN55oARYftBscNHUTaDM4Kgi8OBmFqgA-B0IKBhUeQC+BSKWCKDo1dC16ACCiKb8HQBK0Fiekvw7ewA8VTWUAHygALygANo99S1tHQBERJnfND6AyGI0sPwAhN9QHNZs0PqhWu1QN9IK0Ab1+oNhuYwcieFCFgBdApFEplSrrTYAEWQgwaPWqJ0sZ1eekmXUJHRuG0o8zyS1QKz8-COJwA8qgzlzKZQaXTHj0xdlcjwbIhCH4AKKoCjCAAUa1uGAuWH4PD8WGYBqeDxesgRbRo6EJAEoXQBuRbLeLQHiSQjoPXC0W4CVnF15YAAKnpzV+ui03w6jWacYd0CTyL+idhqe+QKxoNQme+kJ6MJ6KLRyZ6acRJdRfgBteRBZBOOLP3x5fmzSjwAKQA)

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation and the help!